# Exception not found while performing the request in the service account with the new rooms

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I created a new resource (room) and tried to use it with the software I developed to list the events of a room.

```
 GoogleCredential credential;
 string[] scopes = new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
 using (var stream =
                new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                        .CreateScoped(scopes);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Calendar-Project"
            });


            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(googleID);
            Events eventsg = request.Execute();

            .......
```

Using the new room's calendar ID I get the error "not found"...the "old" rooms work correctly.

The calendar ID is correct (I'm sure).

I noticed that however it is different from the IDs of the "old rooms":

**OLD ID** : xxxxxxxxx.it_1884b9j7r3nr4gbanborb21m3jj8i6ga74oj2chh6so34chm@resource.calendar.google.com

**NEW ID** : xxxxxxxxx.it_1889krjg9ra36gtviaih6imjm9tpe@resource.calendar.google.com

Comment: whats googlId?   have you tried doing a calendar.list  to see what calendars you have access to?  sounds to me like your service account doesnt have acess.

Comment: How did you create the room and its calendar? What do you mean by `old rooms`?

Comment: @DaImTo: You were right! Access problems! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"not found" error normally means that you are trying to access a calendar that you don't actually have access to.

If you do a calendar.list you can see which calendars you have access to and then use that instead of your googleId.

Also you can use the term primary to mean the main calendar of the currently authenticated user.  It is also their email address.